# Using SELECT DISTINCT in MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, distinct

Been doing a lot of searching and haven't really found an answer to my MYSQL issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, type, state, country FROM table
```

Results in 1,795 records

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table
```

Results in 1,504 records

For each duplicate "name"... "type", "state", "country" aren't matching in each record.

Trying to figure out how to SELECT the associated row to the DISTINCT name, without checking them for being DISTINCT or not

Comment: It has nothing to do with php, so I deleted the tag

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having some difficulty understanding your questions. Could you post a cut-down version of the data, and explain what it is you want?

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns-postgresql

Comment: you might want to add a sample of the output. something along the lines of ... here are 3 rows with duplicate name but different type, state, country. [3 rows here :-)] and i want [desired output rows]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
SELECT name, type, state, country FROM table GROUP BY name;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: what would be the full query to SELECT DISTINCT by group?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Probably my fault, haven't slept today :-)

Comment: you don't need distinct, for a columns that is grouped. as defined `group by name` summarizes everything with the same `name`. so every `name` is unique in the result

Comment: Did you check that query? IMO there need to be any form of aggregation on any column not in the group by clause.

Comment: I had no idea that GROUP BY only would group unique names.  That did do the trick, thank you very much!

Comment: Not really, this will select exactly one row for every unique name, other rows will be ignored.

Comment: Please note: According to this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html When using this feature, all rows in each group should have the same values for the columns that are ommitted from the GROUP BY part. 
When you group by 'name' and there are several 'types'/'states'/'countries' for a single 'name' value, then MySQL will take indeterminate 'type'/'state'/'country' value for each 'name' in the result set.

Comment: @cypher when trying to create a mysql_query in PHP with that query I get "Resource id#3"

$sql = mysql_query('SELECT name, type, state, country FROM table GROUP BY name');

Goal would be able to do a while loop to INSERT each row into a new table

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) { }

Comment: If i got it right, what you want to do is this? <?php $q = mysql_query('SELECT blabla GROUP BY something'); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) mysql_query('INSERT INTO some_table (some_column, some_other_column) VALUES ("'.$row['some_value'].'", "'.$row['other_value'].'")' ); ?> ?

Comment: And does it work now? Edit: by the way, the right way to do this is to create a stored procedure http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html, it will be much faster than this, you'll only need to mysql_query('call MyProcedure()');

Comment: Very suprising for me that mysql doesn't require specifying aggregates on non-grouped columns. What does it return in them? Mins?

Comment: @FrantišekŽiačik what it returns depends on the ordering. E.g.: `GROUP BY name ORDER BY state DESC` would return each unique name with the highest state for that name. Even though MySQL violates the SQL standard, I find this behavior quite useful at times.

Comment: Warning to others stumbling on this question: Be very careful to pay attention to this discussion regarding aggregates on the non-grouped columns!  The code in this answer, though it's technically correct, is dangerous and misleading.

Answer (score 2):

If you want distinct name, you must decide which of the multiple values that may occur for each distinct name you want. For example, you may want minimals, or counts:

`SELECT name, min(type), min(state), count(country) FROM table GROUP BY name`